# Requirejs: module loading timeout

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Actually I'm facing an irritating problem with Requirejs and Backbone.
I'm developing my App on two different paths:

1. the main access, for example: /App/index.php#list
2. the sub access, for example: /App/index.php/clone#list

The problem appear when I need to load a module with the method require([module]).

If I use the absolute path, like `require(['/App/js/views/modal.js'])` I just obtain this error:

> Error: Load timeout for modules: /App/js/views/modal.js
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

If I use a relative way, like `require(['js/views/modal.js'])` on my main access and `require(['../js/views/modal.js'])` on my sub access, everything work as expected.

I'm loading other modules with the absolute path and they work, if I duplicate the module and require it with a different name it works, I tink the only difference is that the module I'm requiring has already been definited in another module and so it has already been loaded, like this:

**Main module**

```
require('/App/js/views/row.js'], function(Row){
     Somecode...
});

....

require('/App/js/views/modal.js'], function(Modal){
     Othercode...
});
```

**Row Module**

```
define([
'backbone',
'text!templates/row.html',
'views/modal', //the same view callend in my main file!
], function(Backbone, rowTemplate, Modal){
    Viewcode...
});
```

**Modal Module**

```
define([
'backbone',
'text!templates/modal.html',
'models/user_model',
], function(Backbone, modalTemplate, Model){
    Viewcode...
});
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't get the logic behind this, why isn't working with the absolute address?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to append `.js` on to the end of filenames in require.js, and I have seen odd behaviour in doing so myself. Also I'd advise you within the various modules of your application to use relative paths as it makes dragging and dropping modules / components of your app into another application more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I've "fixed" this with a little workaround, by making the main access looks the same as the secondary (`/App/index.php/main#list`), so I can just use relative paths.

Comment: So it was a misconfiguration in the `paths` or `baseUrl` config parameter? Please mark the correct answer then or create your own answer and mark it. Just don't let this question hanging like this.